How to connect a double header to uneven joist ends?
I have a cellar head which I'd like to convert into a pantry, with floorboards and a trapdoor to access the steps down (we don't often use the cellar).
Attached is a rough sketch of what I'm planning, both showing the view without the floorboards, and one with:

I want to use a double header to take angle iron that'll take the weight of the cellar door on either side (angle iron is red on the drawing). However, the existing joists I have (which run across from the hallway - green in the drawing) were just hacked off when the house was built some 150 years ago. This means they all project different lengths into the space.
What's the best way to tackle this?

I did think about it, but they’re pretty difficult to access, and have pipes running alongside, so not as simple as it might look on the drawing unfortunately

That seems like important information to include in your question post.

I would think you would want a "beam" to span from the top green joist down past the bottom green joist to the next intact joist (not shown in your sketch).  Double or triple up the beam so that all joists meet it and trim the joists to fit.
